# Como posso fazer para limpar o que vai para url do formulário usando o método GET com laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Como posso fazer para limpar uma `URL` de busca no `laravel`?
Ja adicionei o comando `addslashes` e o `strip_tags` do `PHP` porem não esta limpando a `URL`.

exemplo:
Se eu passar dentro do input na minha busca `exemplo<?php echo 'alguma coisa' ?>` vai aparecer na minha `URL` desta forma
`http://localhost:8000/busca?busca=exemplo%3C%3Fphp+echo+%27alguma+coisa%27+%3F%3E` como eu poderia fazer para ficar somente desta forma
`http://localhost:8000/busca?busca=exemplo` ?

É possível fazer isso?

aqui está a parte do `controller`:

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Search;
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;

    class SearchController extends Controller{
        
        public function search(){
    
            $requests = addslashes(strip_tags(trim(request('busca'))));
            $slug = Str::slug(Str::lower($requests), '-');
            $results = Search::where('slug', 'LIKE', '%'.$slug.'%')->paginate(1)->withQueryString();
    
            return view('site.busca', ['results' => $results]);
          
        }
    }
```

aqui está a parte do formulário:

```html
    <form action="{{addslashes(strip_tags(trim(route('search'))))}}" method="GET">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="busca" placeholder="Buscar...">
    </form>
```

e aqui está a `route` responsável:

```php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\SearchController;
    
    Route::get('/busca', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```

Comment: Não deve ser uma preocupação do frontend se o cliente aparentemente possa criar uma solicitação maliciosa. O cliente sempre irá conseguir enviar qualquer coisa em uma solicitação ao servidor seja por meio da barra de endereços do navegador, de ferramentas de depuração e desenvolvimento, através de AI bots ou puppet bots, ou solicitação direta. O [tratamento e assepssia](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filter.filters.php) de dados é responsabilidade do servidor realizado após recepcionar dados de uma solicitação e antes que esses dados sejam manipulados ou salvos.

Comment: eu ja limpei ele para o back end `$requests = addslashes(strip_tags(trim(request('busca'))))` agora o que eu quero é limpar na url para nao ficar daquela forma exemplificado acima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu arquivo de rotas você não precisa mexer em nada, ele está correto.
Já no seu arquivo do formulário você está passando os parâmetros de maneira errada. Observe o exemplo abaixo de como fazer da maneira mais correta.

```html
//Antigo
<form action="{{addslashes(strip_tags(trim(route('search'))))}}" method="GET">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" name="busca"              placeholder="Buscar...">
</form>
    
//Novo
<form action="{{route('search')}}" method="GET">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" name="busca" placeholder="Buscar...">
</form>
```

E agora no seu arquivo do controller você vai Adicionar o parâmetro Request do proprio laravel para recuperar todos os dados recebidos do formulário. Então seu arquivo vai ficar assim.

```html
public function search(Request $request){
    
  $busca = $request->busca;
  $slug = Str::slug(Str::lower($busca), '-');
  $results = Search::where('slug', 'LIKE', '%'.$slug.'%')->paginate(1)->withQueryString();
    
 return view('site.busca', ['results' => $results]);     
}
```